# append! cuts strings into characters, push! doesn't [Julia]

Tags: arrays, tuples, julia

**Objective:** 
I need a tuple like (Float, string, int, string, int, string, int, ...). 
Since I calculate the entries over the course of my program, I first add them to an array/vector.

**Attempt:**

```
my_array = []
append!(my_array, 0.1) 
append!(my_array, "ab") 
append!(my_array, 2) 

println(tuple(my_array...))

# Bad output
(0.1, 'a', 'b', 2)
```

**Question:** 
How can I get

```
# Good output
(0.1, "ab", 2)
```

instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the tuple construction, but an appearent misunderstanding of `append!`:

```
julia> append!(my_array, 0.1)

1-element Vector{Any}:
 0.1

julia> append!(my_array, "ab")
3-element Vector{Any}:
 0.1
  'a': ASCII/Unicode U+0061 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
  'b': ASCII/Unicode U+0062 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
```

`append!` appends the elements of any iterable (under which scalar numbers are subsumed) *individually* to an array.  Strings are iterables of characters.

Instead, use `push!`:

```
julia> my_array2 = []
Any[]

julia> push!(my_array2, 0.1)
1-element Vector{Any}:
 0.1

julia> push!(my_array2, "ab")
2-element Vector{Any}:
 0.1
  "ab"

julia> push!(my_array2, 2)
3-element Vector{Any}:
 0.1
  "ab"
 2

julia> Tuple(my_array2)
(0.1, "ab", 2)
```

(Unfortunately, this is inconsistent with `append` and `extend` from Python... but you get used to it.)

Comment: Amazing, thanks! :) Under no circumstances I would have thought of that

Comment: One of the reasons why printf-debugging is still my to-go technique.

Comment: Why couldn't you see this with a 'normal' debugger?